# Cron expression for running rake task first Thursday of every month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I have written following ruby code in rails application :

```
every '20 8 1-7 * 4' do
  rake 'data_import:check_for_presence_of_file'
end
```

But above rake task is running ever day at 8:20 am GMT. Is there something wrong with expression ? I have searched internet for cron expression but I have seen conflicting information. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried this?

    0 9 1-7 * *   [ "$(date '+\%u')" = "1" ]

Based on https://superuser.com/questions/428807/run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-monday-of-every-month ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way with cron.
'20 8 1-7 * 4' means the first seven days of the month and on thursdays. Instead perhaps do it the first seven days of the month and in rails check if its thursday:

```
every '20 8 1-7 * *' do
  rake 'data_import:check_for_presence_of_file' if Date.today.thursday?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct cron schedule for a Tuesday weekly:

```
20 8 * * 2
```

Here are more details:
https://crontab.guru/#20_8_*_*_2

In your sample you are using `1-7` which means every day.

Comment: Read the headline. He wanted the first thursday each month, not a weekly run. And 1-7 means the first seven days of the month.